# JavaFX Tableviews - compare and highlight cells

Tags: javafx-8

i am quite new to Javafx, and would like your help in solving the below:

I have two tableviews, and i would like to compare the column values between the two and highlight the cell of one of the tables, if the values are different.
(Assumption - both tables have same number of columns, restricting rows to the minimum content among tables)

ex:
table 1 has
column1    column2    column3
1          America    Newyork

table 2 has
column1    column2    column3
1          America    Washington

The second table last column should be highlighted with a textfill

I have this pseudo code, doesnt seem to work though

```
           int colsize1= tableview1.getColumns().size();
    int colsize2= tableview2.getColumns().size();

    if(colsize1 != colsize2) {

        alert("number of columns do not match, cannot be validated");
        return;
    }

    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> da1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<ObservableList<String>> da2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    da1.addAll(tableview1.getItems());
    da2.addAll(tableview2.getItems());

    int size = Math.min(da1.size(), da2.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < colsize1; j++) {

               if(!(tableview1.getItems().get(i).get(j).equals(tableview2.getItems().get(i).get(j)))) {
                   String value = tableview1.getItems().get(i).get(j);
                   String value2 = tableview2.getItems().get(i).get(j);
                   int currentrow = i;

                   TableColumn<TableView<ObservableList<String>>, String> columns = (TableColumn) tableview2.getColumns().get(j);

                   columns.setCellFactory(column -> {
                       return new TableCell<TableView<ObservableList<String>>, String>() {

                           @Override
                           protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                               super.updateItem(item, empty);


                               System.out.println("item is " + item + " empty is " + empty);
                               if(empty){

                                   if(value != value2){
                                       this.setStyle("-fx-background-color : yellow");
                                   }
                               }

                               if (!empty) {

                                   if((value != item) && currentrow == getTableRow().getIndex()) {

                                       //  int rowindex =  getTableRow().getIndex();

                                       System.out.println(" item is " + item);

                                       this.setText(item);
                                       this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                       this.setStyle("-fx-background-color : yellow");
                                   }else {
                                       this.setText(item);
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       };
                   });
               }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found a solution to the given problem. my code is -

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the given problem.

@FXML
    public void onvalidatebutton() {

```
    int colsize1 = tableview1.getColumns().size();
    int colsize2 = tableview2.getColumns().size();

    if (colsize1 != colsize2) {

        alert("number of columns do not match, cannot be validated");
        return;
    }

    int size = tableview1.getItems().size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < colsize1; j++) {

            TableColumn columns2 = tableview2.getColumns().get(j);

          //     String value = tableview1.getItems().get(currentrow).get(j);

            settingcell(columns2);
        }
    }

    }


private void settingcell(TableColumn<ObservableList<String>,String> column) {

    column.setCellFactory(col -> {
        return new TableCell<ObservableList<String>, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (!empty) {

                   int ind =  getTableView().getVisibleLeafIndex(column);

                  //  System.out.println(" ind is " + ind);

                   String value = tableview1.getItems().get(this.getIndex()).get(ind);

                  //  System.out.println(" value is " + value + " & item is "+ item);
                        if (!(StringUtils.equals(value,item))) {

                            this.setText(item);
                            this.setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            this.setStyle("-fx-background-color : yellow");

                        } else {
                            this.setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        this.setText("");
                    }
            }
        };
    });
}
```